# Equivalent of php include in c#?

Tags: c#, import, include

Is there any way to import classes and other files in c# like "include" in PHP ?

Comment: No! I mean that I want to import another c# class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `include` in C#.  The closest you can get is creating classes that reside in namespaces, then generate a `using` for that namespace.

For example, say you create a class in a separate file of your project and assign it to a namespace:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace.SecondNamespace 
{
    public static class HelloWorld 
    {
        public static string Greet { get { return "Hello, World!"; } }
    }
}
```

Now, in your main project, you can reference that namespace in two ways.  Let's assume your main project files look something like this:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    public class WhatWeDo
    {
        public void WeGreetTheWorld()
        {
            // Here, we greet the world
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to put our `HelloWorld` class into the above code, we can either reference it directly, or add a using to the top of the page.  For fully referenced method, substitute the comment above for:

```
public void WeGreetTheWorld()
{
    string greeting = ProjectNamespace.SecondNamespace.HelloWorld.Greet;
}
```

Or, we can add `using ProjectNamespace.SecondNamespace` to the top of the file, then just reference the class directly.

```
using ProjectNamespace.SecondNamespace;

namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    public class WhatWeDo
    {
         public void We GreetTheWorld()
         {
             string greeting = HelloWorld.Greet;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you create assemblies that may be [referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in other projects. Those assemblies contain classes that are declared inside namespaces which are brought into scope with the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423) directive:

```
using NamespaceName;
```

Comment: tnx. but where should I keep my files ?

Comment: Once you compile a project, this project gets compiled into an assembly (DLL or EXE). It is this assembly that you reference in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare in the top of your file, this:

```
using System.Collections;
```